# Universal Group in domain not behaving as expected in multi-forest environment

Tags: active-directory

I have an environment with 2 forests, F1 and F2 with a full, transitive, bi-directional trust between them. F1 has a single domain that holds an SSRS server. F2 has 2 domains, F2parent and F2child, parent and child domains respectively.

On the SSRS server I need to give access to a security group in F2parent that holds users who lives in F2child.

As a Universal Group this does not work, as a Domain Local group it works. My understanding is that it should work as a Universal Group. Why doesn't it?